# VFY: unable to find class referend in signature

Tags: android, verifyerror

In my android project i use other projects as librarys. They are added in the build path as Projects and in Order and Export

```
03-16 19:54:32.418: I/System.out(27217): Antes del unmarshal
03-16 19:55:36.488: W/dalvikvm(27217): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/api/ReadableRepresentation;)
03-16 19:55:36.488: I/dalvikvm(27217): Could not find method com.theoryinpractise.halbuilder.api.ReadableRepresentation.getValue, referenced from method com.theoryinpractise.halbuilder.jaxrs.HalUnmarshaller.getObjectFromRepresentation
03-16 19:55:36.488: W/dalvikvm(27217): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 11651: Lcom/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/api/ReadableRepresentation;.getValue (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
03-16 19:55:36.488: D/dalvikvm(27217): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x003e
03-16 19:55:36.498: W/dalvikvm(27217): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1502 (Lcom/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/api/RepresentationException;)
03-16 19:55:36.498: W/dalvikvm(27217): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x58
03-16 19:55:36.508: W/dalvikvm(27217): VFY:  rejected Lcom/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/jaxrs/HalUnmarshaller;.getObjectFromRepresentation (Lcom/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/api/ReadableRepresentation;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
03-16 19:55:36.508: W/dalvikvm(27217): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0058
03-16 19:55:36.508: W/dalvikvm(27217): VFY:  rejected Lcom/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/jaxrs/HalUnmarshaller;.getObjectFromRepresentation (Lcom/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/api/ReadableRepresentation;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
03-16 19:55:36.508: W/dalvikvm(27217): Verifier rejected class Lcom/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/jaxrs/HalUnmarshaller;
03-16 19:55:45.828: W/System.err(27217): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.VerifyError: com/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/jaxrs/HalUnmarshaller
03-16 19:55:45.848: W/System.err(27217):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:93)
03-16 19:55:45.848: W/System.err(27217):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)
03-16 19:55:45.858: W/System.err(27217):    at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:483)
03-16 19:55:45.858: W/System.err(27217):    at com.example.modelo.ObtieneRecursos.obtieneTokenMe(ObtieneRecursos.java:49)
03-16 19:55:45.868: W/System.err(27217):    at com.example.pestanasholacampus.InitActivity.compruebaUsuario(InitActivity.java:123)
03-16 19:55:45.878: W/System.err(27217):    at com.example.pestanasholacampus.InitActivity$2.onClick(InitActivity.java:68)
03-16 19:55:45.878: W/System.err(27217):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
03-16 19:55:45.878: W/System.err(27217):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
03-16 19:55:45.878: W/System.err(27217):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-16 19:55:45.878: W/System.err(27217):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-16 19:55:45.888: W/System.err(27217):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-16 19:55:45.888: W/System.err(27217):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
03-16 19:55:45.888: W/System.err(27217):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 19:55:45.888: W/System.err(27217):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-16 19:55:45.888: W/System.err(27217):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-16 19:55:45.888: W/System.err(27217):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
03-16 19:55:45.898: W/System.err(27217):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 19:55:45.898: W/System.err(27217): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/jaxrs/HalUnmarshaller
03-16 19:55:45.898: W/System.err(27217):    at com.example.modelo.ObtencionTokenUsuario.doInBackground(ObtencionTokenUsuario.java:60)
03-16 19:55:45.898: W/System.err(27217):    at com.example.modelo.ObtencionTokenUsuario.doInBackground(ObtencionTokenUsuario.java:1)
03-16 19:55:45.898: W/System.err(27217):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-16 19:55:45.908: W/System.err(27217):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-16 19:55:45.908: W/System.err(27217):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-16 19:55:45.908: W/System.err(27217):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-16 19:55:45.908: W/System.err(27217):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-16 19:55:45.908: W/System.err(27217):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I only see one rare thing in the buildPath. It only contains this: 
[image]
I have read another posts with this problem but i dont know why does not works if the build path contains the projects.
All helps are welcome. Thanks.